# How to scale up named channels by having kafka as a transport layer

Tags: spring-xd

I'm using Spring XD 1.2.1 with kafka as a transport layer. I have the follow set up:

xd:
  transport: kafka
  messagebus:
    kafka:
      default:
        concurrency:        10
        minPartitionCount:  10

I have the following streams as example:

**Streams**

```
stream create f --definition "queue:foo > transform --expression=payload+'-foo' | log" 
stream create b --definition "queue:bar > transform --expression=payload+'-bar' | log"
stream deploy --name f --properties "module.transform.count=2"
stream deploy --name b --properties "module.transform.count=2"
stream create r --definition "time | router --expression=payload.contains('10')?'queue:foo':'queue:bar'" --deploy
```

**Question**

How can I scale up the first processor in the streams which "source" is a named channel? I was expecting something like 20 partitions in the transformers of the streams f and b, as long as the count is 2, and the concurrency is 10. But the number of partitions are 10.

This is working as expected when you deploy other modules that are not the first.

Should I configure the named channels in a specific way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The kafka partitions are controlled by the producing side.

For a mid-stream channel we can look at the "next" module and calculate the partition count by calculating its needs (`concurrency*count`).

With a named channel, we have no way of knowing the number of consumers (or their concurrency) so a count and concurrency of 1 is used, and so `minPartitionCount` is used as the partition count.

You would need to deploy the producing stream with an appropriate setting to increase the partitions:

```
stream deploy foo --properties module.last.producer.minPartitionCount=20
```

**EDIT**

Actually - it looks like we have a bug - you can't specifiy the `minPartitionCount` on a named channel.

I see you have opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3697).

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the answer, that is perfectly clear :)